# Is there any way where we can call a custom hook inside useeffect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const useApiCall = (asyncFunction, body) => {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [cancel, setCancel] = useState(null);
  const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);
  const execute = useCallback(async cancelPromise => {
    try {
      setFetching(true);
      setResponse(null);
      setError(null);
      setFetched(false);
      setCancel(() => {
        return cancelPromise.cancel;
      });
      let result = await cancelPromise.promise;
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (ex) {
      setError(ex);
    } finally {
      setFetching(false);
      setFetched(true);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cancelPromise = body
      ? makeCancelable(asyncFunction(body))
      : makeCancelable(asyncFunction());
    execute(cancelPromise);
    return () => cancelPromise.cancel();
  }, [asyncFunction, body, execute]);

  return { fetching, response, error, fetched, cancel };
};
```

As this hook returns 4 states of an api call i would like to use this hook inside another hook but conditionally. 
should I create another parameter that will call the api conditionally?
for example accept another parameter say shouldCall api (bool)
and add a condition above the execute method mentioned in the useEffect?

Comment: hook is not suppose to call inside hook. you can creat a emitter function, of service to emit events and bind to hook.

Comment: Do you wish to execute the api conditionally? and if so, what kind of condition?

Comment: the condition could be anything. let's say an api call on page load and based on the response call another api using the same hook